# Simplepie plugin causing an internal server error?

Tags: simplepie

My website host did some checking for me and indicated that Simplepie plugin is causing a memory problem.  Can you say which files need to be removed in order to access my Sopacameraclub.com site again?  below is the info provided to me:

[3:23:25 AM]Vyshnavi Gottumukkala:From the error logs I see 20180118T164756: www.sopacameraclub.com/wp-admin/index.php
PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 118489088) (tried to allocate 1966080 bytes) in /hermes/bosnaweb08a/b2428/ipg.sopacameraclubcom/wp-includes/SimplePie/Item.php on line 2736
[3:25:03 AM]Vyshnavi Gottumukkala:From the error, I see issue with SimplePie application . Please contact the vendor and correct it or you can remove the files from your website

Answer (score 0):

Simplepie was not causing the problem.  I had too many plugins loaded which was causing the memory problem.  Once I deactivated enough plugins there was enough memory to keep my site running.